# Better way to send lots of text to a server?

Tags: java, php, sql

I have a java application that sends text to a sql database on a server. Currently my java application takes the text, puts it into the url, then sends it to a php page on the server that takes it with GET and puts it in the database. that works fine to an extent, the problem is, that i need to be able to send lots of text, and i keep getting 414, uri to long errors. is there a better way to do this?

ok, i tried what you said, and read the tutorial, but something is not working. here is my code that i tried

```
public  void submitText(String urls,String data) throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL(urls);
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

    con.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
    out.write(data);
    out.flush();


}
submitText(server + "publicPB.php", "param=" +  text);
```

here is my php code

```
$param = $_POST['param'];
$sql = "UPDATE table SET cell='{$param}' WHERE 1";
mysql_query($sql);
...
```

im pretty sure its not a problem with the php as the php worked fine with GET, and thats all i change with it, my problem i think is that im not 100% sure how to send data to it with the java

Comment: If that is really your php code spend a bit of time reading about SQL injection

Comment: i know -_-  this is a basic example showing what i am doing, not the actual code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `POST` instead of a `GET` and send the text as the request body. You can only pass so much data to a URL. E.g.:

```
// Assuming 'input' is a String and contains your text
URL url = new URL("http://hostname/path");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
con.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
out.write(input);
out.close();
```

See [Reading from and Writing to a URLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) for more details.

Comment: how do i use POST from a remote app? as far as i know, post is only on the same server?

Comment: Update my answer with an example of posting with `URLConnection`.

Comment: Ok, i updated my code, and its not working, im not exactly sure how to use it, i updated my post with the code im using

Comment: I'm not proficient with PHP however you might want to try removing the `"param="` on the Java side and read it with `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` on the PHP side.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `POST` to send data across to PHP page? `GET` does have a [smaller limit of content](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use POST requests, which do not have content length limits.

Answer (score 0):

POST requests do not have length content limits and are much secure than GET requests ;)

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL Server I would look into leveraging [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).  You can write the file and call BCP from within Java, and it will send the information directly to your database.